# A question about fundamental invariants in the context of neural networks

Tags: invariant-theory, machine-learning

I'm reading in depth the first part of the following paper: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1804.10306.pdf, paying specific attention to the following result, that I re-write here for the sake of convenience:

[Yarotsky, 2018]

*Let $\Gamma$ be a compact group, $V$ a finite-dimensional $\Gamma$-module and $f_1, \dots f_{N_{inv}} : V \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ a finite generating sets of polynomial invariants on $V$ (existing due to Hilbert's finiteness theorem). Then any continuous invariant map $f:V \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$* can be approximated by invariant maps $\hat{f}:V \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ of the form:

$$\hat{f}(\textbf{x}) = \sum_{n=1}^Nc_n\left(\sum_{s=1}^{N_{inv}}w_{ns}f_s(\textbf{x}) + h_n\right)$$

with some parameter $N$ and coefficients $c_n, w_{ns},h_n.$

The above equation represents a (theoretically) universal $\Gamma$-invariant neural network.

The problem is that most of the times the fundamental invariants $f_1, \dots f_{N_{inv}}$ are unknown, but in some cases we actually know what they correspond to. Indeed, if $\Gamma = S_n$ then $f_1, \dots f_{N_{inv}}$ are nothing but the [elementary symmetric polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_symmetric_polynomial), and there is a nice [theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_symmetric_polynomial#Fundamental_theorem_of_symmetric_polynomials) stating that any polynomial invariant can be written as the polynomial expression of elementary symmetric functions.

Now what I'm trying to do, is to understand better the above result, in light of the previous considerations:

Let's say we have some input features with four dimensions, $\textbf{x} \in V:=\mathbb{R}^4$, we take $\Gamma := S_4$,  and we want to approximate an invariant function $f :\mathbb{R}^4 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.

Then:

$$f_1(\textbf{x})= x_1 + x_2 +x_3 +x_4,$$
$$f_2(\textbf{x})= x_1x_2 + x_1x_3 +x_2x_3 +x_2x_4+x_3x_4,$$
$$f_3(\textbf{x})= x_1x_2x_3 + x_1x_2x_4 +x_1x_3x_4+x_2x_3x_4,$$
$$f_4(\textbf{x})= x_1x_2x_3x_4.$$

So basically we should change the inputs $x_1, x_2,x_3,x_4$ we would normally feed to the network, by creating elementary symmetric polynomials out of the features?